# Is @Transactional support for NamedParameterTemplate.batchUpdate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, transactions, batch-updates

Is @Transactional support for NamedParameterTemplate.batchUpdate?
If something went wrong during the batch execution, will it rollback as expected? Personally, I am not experienced that. That's why I am asking. 
Is there any document to check @Transactional supported methods.

```
public class JdbcActorDao implements ActorDao {

private NamedParameterTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;

public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.namedParameterJdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}

@Transactional
public int[] batchUpdate(List<Actor> actors) {
    return this.namedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(
            "update t_actor set first_name = :firstName, last_name = :lastName where id = :id",
            SqlParameterSourceUtils.createBatch(actors));
}

// ... additional methods
```

}

Comment: Whether you use batch updates or simple updates, these updates happen during the transaction, and rollbacking the transaction will rollback the updates. If in doubt, why don't you just test it?

Comment: I tested it. it is not working. that's why I am asking.

Comment: I was unable to found the proper documentation to verify what are methods support by Transactional annotation.

Comment: Then ask that in your question. Show how you got an instance of your DAO and how you called its method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NamedParameterTemplate is just an abstraction around Jdbc. In spring it is the Transaction Manager that is responsible for managing transactions, not that you can not do it via plain JDBC but this is the spring way. Spring uses AOP internaly to inspect the annotated methods and delegates its transaction managment. But this role is separate from the NamedParameterTemplate.

So you can use it freely and annotate your methods as long as they are within a Spring managed component/bean  with @Transactional